# How do you create a second taskbar to use on multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I recently got myself a second monitor and I have been looking at software which offers the possibility to extend the taskbar to the second monitor. Softwares such as UltraMon and MultiMon offer such possibility.

I'd be interested to know what is the method they are using to replicate the tasbar? More precisely:

- Is the second taskbar completely generated and managed by the software or is it some sort of extension/modification of how Windows behave?
- How are the additionnal buttons on the window handle added? Is there some sort of templating system similar to what Stardock does?
- How can you replicate the taskbar feel?
- How can you remove open software icons from the main taskbar in order to move them to the software's taskbar?
- Would creating a second start button actually be some sort of image of the said button, and the software would require to do POSSIBLE calls to the Windows API? (by possible, I mean I have no idea if such calls exists)

Finally, I'd be interested to know what field of knowledge is required to program such software.

I'd be glad to receive any pointers to articles or information that would lead to answers. If you have in depth knowledge that you'd gladly share, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks to all for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They completely re-create the experience. DisplayFusion uses the Desktop Window Manager API to capture live thumbnails. Scott Hanselman [has a very good rundown](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNearFinalWordOnMultiMonitorTaskbarsForWindows7UltramonVsDisplayFusion.aspx) on just how close they got and where they're different.

I would imagine there is a lot of ugly code required to get it as close as they've gotten it.

Comment: Update: DisplayFusion ist the answer and also works in portable mode